# Count If with Condition Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
   A    B    C   
0  xx   No   1
1  xx   No   2
2  xx   Yes  3
3  xx   Yes  4
4  xx   No   1
5  xx   No   2
6  xx   No   3
7  xx   Yes  4
8  xx   No   1
9  xx   No   2
```

If want to create a column that counts the number of times a number appear in column C, when column B is equal to Yes

so the output would be

```
   A    B    C   countifs   
0  xx   No   1      
1  xx   No   2
2  xx   Yes  3      1
3  xx   Yes  4      2
4  xx   No   1
5  xx   No   2
6  xx   No   3
7  xx   Yes  4      2
8  xx   No   1
9  xx   No   2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For count only `True`s values use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` only for filtered rows by mask:

```
m = df['B'].eq('Yes')
df['countifs'] = m.groupby(df.loc[m, 'C']).transform('sum').fillna('')
print (df)
    A    B  C countifs
0  xx   No  1         
1  xx   No  2         
2  xx  Yes  3        1
3  xx  Yes  4        2
4  xx   No  1         
5  xx   No  2         
6  xx   No  3         
7  xx  Yes  4        2
8  xx   No  1         
9  xx   No  2
```

Comment: thanks alot. Is it possible to group this with another column as well? so C and A?

Comment: @fred.schwartz - Yes, aonly assign column `m` like `df['countifs'] = df.assign(m=m).groupby(['C', 'B'])['m'].transform('sum').fillna('')`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
y = df.B.eq('Yes')
df.loc[y, 'countifs'] = df[y].groupby('C').B.transform('count').values

print(df.fillna(''))

   A    B   C countifs
0  xx   No  1         
1  xx   No  2         
2  xx  Yes  3        1
3  xx  Yes  4        2
4  xx   No  1         
5  xx   No  2         
6  xx   No  3         
7  xx  Yes  4        2
8  xx   No  1         
9  xx   No  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), and [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map):

```
>>> col_C_cnts = df[df.B == 'Yes']['C'].value_counts()
>>> df['countifs'] = np.where(df.B == 'Yes', df['C'].map(col_C_cnts), pd.np.nan)
>>> print(df.fillna(''))
    A    B  C countifs
0  xx   No  1         
1  xx   No  2         
2  xx  Yes  3        1
3  xx  Yes  4        2
4  xx   No  1         
5  xx   No  2         
6  xx   No  3         
7  xx  Yes  4        2
8  xx   No  1         
9  xx   No  2
```